# Octave Multiple Colors in Single Plot

Tags: colors, plot, octave

Consider X, Y and Z as n-columnar vector where, Z only has values 1-6.

Then, I would like to plot

```
for i=1:n
    if Z(i) == 1
       plot(X(i), Y(i), @1)
       hold on
    elseif
       plot(X(i), Y(i), @2)
       ...
```

What I would like to do is accomplish this in single line as

```
plot(X, y, 'color', Z).
```

Is there a way to do so?
(In short, can my settings (color in this instance) be dictated by third vector? )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to plot each pair of coordinates `x(i), y(i)` using color `z(i)`. Use the `scatter()` function:

```
scatter(x,y,[],z)
```

`z` can be either a vector or a matrix where each row is a RGB color specification.